# Incorrect syntax near (last line)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a stored procedure, and when I converted it back from a query to a stored procedure, it's complaining about "incorrect syntax near 0", or wherever the last line is if I comment things out.

I have a feeling it's my BEGIN/END statements since this is my first time using them, but I thought it worked before I converted from a SP to a query to do more testing.  The BEGIN/END statements look good to me.  The error seems to go away when I uncomment the END after SET @error_message, but there's no BEGIN to match it.

Any ideas? This is my stored procedure:

```
USE [DB_DEV]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MemberInd]    Script Date: 3/23/2020 3:37:07 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MemberInd]
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @error_message varchar
    SET @error_message = N'***'

    DECLARE @count_error int
    SET @count_error = 0

BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        UMC.CID, UMC.CONCEPT_ID, UMC.STR_VALUE, M.TITLE, M.VF_01
    INTO #UMC_TMP
    FROM DB_DEV..U_MEMBER_CONCEPT UMC WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN DB_DEV..MEMBER M WITH (NOLOCK) ON M.CID=UMC.CID AND M.TITLE = 'RR' 
    WHERE UMC.concept_id IN (501)

    SELECT 
        T.CID, T.STR_VALUE,
        CASE
           WHEN T.TITLE = 'RR' AND (T.STR_VALUE IS NULL OR T.STR_VALUE = '') 
              THEN ISNULL(NULLIF(UPPER(T.TITLE), T.VF_01), NULL) -- Title is RR, no member in concept
           WHEN T.TITLE = 'RR' AND STR_VALUE IS NOT NULL 
              THEN 'ERROR' -- Title is RR, member ind has a value
           WHEN (T.TITLE <> 'RR' OR T.TITLE IS NULL) AND T.STR_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND T.STR_VALUE IN ('SF', 'MF') 
              THEN T.STR_VALUE -- Title is not RR, member ind has a value
           WHEN T.TITLE <> 'RR' AND (T.STR_VALUE IS NULL OR T.STR_VALUE = '') 
              THEN NULL -- Title is not RR, no member ind concept
           ELSE NULL
        END MemInd
    INTO #UPDATES
    FROM #UMC_TMP T

    --BEGIN
    UPDATE M
    SET metadata_guid= 'F1CBACCD-9053-412E-86F2-816691E54F9D',VF_01 = MemInd
    FROM #UPDATES U --WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN DB_DEV..MEMBER M WITH (NOLOCK) ON U.CID = M.CID
    WHERE MemInd IS NOT NULL

    SET @count_error = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #UPDATES WHERE MemInd = 'ERROR')

    SET @error_message = (SELECT MemInd, M.CID, STR_VALUE, TITLE 
                          FROM #UPDATES U 
                          INNER JOIN DB_DEV..MEMBER M WITH (NOLOCK) ON U.CID = M.CID 
                          WHERE MemInd = 'ERROR')
--END  --this was an extra END I commented out with no BEGIN

BEGIN

IF @count_error > 0
   THROW 51000, @error_message, 1;  --gives entire error set of 'error'
END

RETURN 0

GO  --red squiggly this line, incorrect syntax line above, but it's fine...
```

Comment: `SET @error_message = (SELECT MemInd, M.CID, STR_VALUE, TITLE ` - you have **one** variable that can hold **one value** - yet in the `SELECT`, you select **FOUR** columns! That can't be right ....

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Your `@error_message` variable is now most likely exactly **ONE** character long ...... is that what you intended?

Comment: You have a `BEGIN` near the start of your SP, you never `END`. The comment `--this was an extra END I commented out with no BEGIN` is wrong, you *do* have a `BEGIN`. It's prior to `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Why are you putting BEGIN...END at apparently random parts of the proc? You only need it to denote blocks e.g. after an IF statement or perhaps to enclose the **whole** stored proc body

Comment: Try moving your `BEGIN` statement up, so it is on the line below your first `AS`.

Comment: @marc_s -  so if I declare varchar of 255 for the error_message, do you think it will provide data from all 4 columns returned? I'm trying to find the best way for them to look into the error if it happens by providing the data for the error.

Comment: @Larnu - I think you're right.  I was confusing the END for the CASE with the END for the BEGIN.

Comment: If you want to combine the four columns into an error message, you need to use `CONCAT` to achieve that - `SET @error_message = SELECT CONCAT(MemInd, M.CID, STR_VALUE, TITLE) FROM ......`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per @marc_s, I made these changes to fix it.  Thank you for your help, Marc.

I was mistaking the CASE END for the BEGIN's END.  I needed to uncomment this line:

```
END  --this was an extra END I commented out with no BEGIN
```

Also, I fixed my error message as follows, but this did not cause my initial question. It did cause errors running the SP, though:

```
DECLARE @error_message varchar(255)
```

..
..

```
SET @error_message = (SELECT CONCAT(M.CID, TITLE, MemInd) FROM #UPDATES U INNER JOIN DB_DEV..MEMBER M WITH (NOLOCK) ON U.CID=M.CID WHERE MemInd='ERROR')
```